# Sort a row of a matrix keeping the col.names along in the resulting matrix in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix with one row X=2 5 7 3 as elements.  Implicitly these elements have column names V1-V4. I want to sort these elements, and once sorted they  have to also carry their column names along, i.e V1-V4. In this example, once sorted I will need a matrix that has sorted the elements to Y=2 3 5 7 being the second row  and 1st row being V1 V4 V2 V3. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @akrun that was a mistake. I corrected it in my question.

Comment: I think the colnames of the result would be `V1 V4 V2 V3`

Comment: @akrun-no I do not get such a result. The colnames always remain as V1 V2 3 V4 even after the numbers are sorted

Comment: I think you may have to show a small reproducible example with the expected result as I got confused with the description.

Answer (score 2):

The column names will naturally move with the column data when you use dimensional indexing:

```
m <- matrix(c(V1=2,5,7,3),1,4,dimnames=list(NULL,c('V1','V2','V3','V4')));
m;
##      V1 V2 V3 V4
## [1,]  2  5  7  3
m <- m[,order(m[1,]),drop=F];
m;
##      V1 V4 V2 V3
## [1,]  2  3  5  7
```

Comment: Thanks @bggoldst. But I forgot to mention that my matrix is 314X16000. So I need to sort all of them individually and I've to know their respective index. In your example, you provide the dimnames explicitly. If I took them out then the final m still gives me V1 V2 V3 V4. In my matrix all the 16K columns have to be sorted and Ive to know their respective indices. What would be the best way to solve such a problem?